# How to retrieve tree nodes children (recursive function help)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have a binary, the database table of relationships looks like this:

```
+----+----------+---------+-----+
| id | parentID | childID | pos |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
|  1 |        1 |       2 | l   |
|  2 |        1 |       3 | r   |
|  3 |        2 |       4 | l   |
|  4 |        3 |       5 | r   |
|  5 |        4 |       6 | l   |
|  6 |        5 |       7 | r   |
+----+----------+---------+-----+
```

I am able to extract or children of for example 1 - but I have very clumsy function for that, so I need something that works better.

The output I need should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parentID] => 1
            [pos] => l
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parentID] => 2
            [pos] => l
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parentID] => 4
            [pos] => l
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [parentID] => 1
            [pos] => r
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parentID] => 3
            [pos] => r
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parentID] => 5
            [pos] => r
        )

)
```

So far I came up with this function, however it returns nested array, I want it flattened ... but whenever I tried it it just fails.

```
function children($pid) {
    //set sql
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE parentID = ".$pid;    
    //save query to result
    $result = mysql_query ($sql)
        or die("Bad request " . mysql_error()); 

    while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        $topchild["id"] = $item["childID"];
        $topchild["parentID"]= $item["parentID"];
        $topchild["pos"] = $item["pos"];        

        $children[] = $topchild;
        $children[] = children($item["childID"]);       
    endwhile;


        return $children;
}
```

What do I do wrong there?

Comment: I don't quite follow you. What is your definition of children? Has node `id=1` just one child (with `id=2`), or do you consider all nodes beneath `id=1` its children? I also don't understand the output you posted. It just looks like a dump of the database table. What's special about it?

Comment: node id=1 has two (immediate) children (2,3), those have another children (4,5,6,7) ... I want to be able to get an array that looks like the one I posted where will be all children of given parent, or specify it by depth parameter (eg. 0 = all, 1 = first level children, etc.) - that I can do I just didnt include it in this function yet

Comment: Err, looking at your table, I see a linked list, not a tree: `1` points to itself (the start, or root), `2` points to `1`, `3` points to `2`, etc: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6`. Your array-output looks different though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want it flattened

```
$children[] = children($item["childID"]);
```

instead add each of the items in the return value separately:

```
foreach (children($item['childID'] as $child)
    $children[]= $child;
```

(Also shouldn't `$topchild` be initialised inside the loop?)

If you are doing a lot of recursive queries like this, a parent-child relation table is not a good choice of data structure. Consider one of the hierarchically-oriented solutions such as [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).